# ADC signal interpolation

Tags: interpolation, approximation

I would like to increase resolution of signal. Signal is captured using ADC with a sample rate of 400ns.

Signal is shown down below:
[ADC signal full](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANGHq.png)
[ADC signal scaled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfmVu.png)

I would like to know what is best solution to increase resolution of signal. I have an adc samples array with fixed 700 samples (let say data[700]), and my adc sample rate is known - it is 400ns. What kind of function I shoud use? Interpolation or approximation?
I would like to increase resolution to at least 10 times. It would be great to store postprocessed data to new array for example 10 times larger than raw array - data_new[7000].

Comment: What do you mean, "resolution?"  There is sampling rate, and sampling bit depth.  This is not really a programming question.  try https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I mean not resolution, but increase quantity of data point using functions such as interpolation or approximation.